# Generar documento word a partir de datos

Tags: ionic, servidor

Estoy desarrollando una app en ionic, y esta manda información a un servidor.
Como puedo generar un documento Word en el servidor a partir de esa información?
Alguien que me oriente o me de una idea

Comment: Lo primero con algo tan genérico no podemos hacer nada. Nos tienes que indicar que lenguaje utiliza el back para poder ayudarte.